# How to save multiple checkbox values to Firebase when a Button is clicked

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, android-checkbox

This is the HTML file. Im having trouble in saving multiple checked box value into firebase. I want to store selected checkbox text to Firebase when the Button is clicked and go to another Activity.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    android:background="#FCFAFA"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/camera"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_bg_round"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:tint="#858585"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera"
                    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                android:paddingLeft="12dp"
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:text="Place "
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/placeName"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:minHeight="40dp"
                        android:padding="8dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:text="Street"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/streetName"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:minHeight="40dp"
                        android:padding="8dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:text="Postcode"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/postcodeName"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:minHeight="40dp"
                        android:padding="8dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:text="City"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/cityName"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@color/transparent"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:minHeight="40dp"
                        android:padding="8dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:text="Facility"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/facility_ramp"
                        android:text="@string/ramp"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/desc_ramp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Description"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/facility_lift"
                        android:text="@string/disabled_lift"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/desc_lift"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Description"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/facility_counter"
                        android:text="@string/counter"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/desc_counter"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Description"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/facility_toilet"
                        android:text="@string/toilet"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/desc_toilet"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Description"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/addBtn"
                android:background="@drawable/searchbutton"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CREATE PLACE"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This are the java code. I havent save the checked box item/dat into firebase because i dont know the java code to store the facility description once the box has been checked. Do help, thank you

```
    //declare
    mAddPlace = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.placeName);
    mAddStreet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.streetName);
    mAddPostcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postcodeName);
    mAddCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cityName);
    mbtnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addBtn);

    mRampCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.facility_ramp);
    mCounterCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.facility_counter);
    mLiftCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.facility_lift);
    mToiletCheckBox = findViewById(R.id.facility_toilet);

    descRamp = findViewById(R.id.desc_ramp);
    descLift = findViewById(R.id.desc_lift);
    descCounter = findViewById(R.id.desc_counter);
    descToilet = findViewById(R.id.desc_toilet);


    mRampCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                descRamp.setEnabled(true);

            }
            else
                descRamp.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });

    mLiftCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                descLift.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
                descLift.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });

    mCounterCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                descCounter.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
                descCounter.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });

    mToiletCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                descToilet.setEnabled(true);
            }
            else
                descToilet.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });
```

Comment: you want to save all check boxes values in one instance?

Comment: i wanted to save the checked values of facility with the description enabled that associated with the place. It mean 1 place can have several facilities checked with its own description to be stored into firebase

Comment: Where in your code are you setting the values to Firebase?

Comment: haven't done the part as i dont really know how to store the values into firebase

Answer (score 0):

```
    private boolean mRamp , mLift , mCounter , mToilet ;   
     private DatabaseReference UserRef;
     private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    
    
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        
    
    
    mRampCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    descRamp.setEnabled(true);
                    mRamp = true;
    
                }
                else
                    descRamp.setEnabled(false);
                    mRamp = false;
    
    
            }
        });
    
        mLiftCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    descLift.setEnabled(true);
                    mLift = true;
                }
                else
                    descLift.setEnabled(false);
                    mLift  = false;
    
            }
        });
    
        mCounterCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    descCounter.setEnabled(true);
                    mCounter = true;
                }
                else
                    descCounter.setEnabled(false);
                    mCounter = false;
    
            }
        });
    
        mToiletCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    descToilet.setEnabled(true);
                    mToilet = true;
                }
                else
                    descToilet.setEnabled(false);
                    mToilet = false;
    
            }
        });
    

}
    
    
    
    private void uploadData()
    {
      HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("mRamp" ,mRamp);
            userMap.put("mLift" ,mLift);
            userMap.put("mCounter" ,mCounter);
            userMap.put("mToilet" ,mToilet);
            
    
            UserRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                      
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

**Call this method where you want to upload the data** uploadData();